# Is there a way to make a function like ask but which accepts multiple lines in Red console?

Tags: red

When using

ask "your answer: "

You cannot paste multiple lines.

Is it possible to control the console to accept multiple lines temporarily ?
Or am I obliged to create a GUI which I'd like to avoid, I don't want any GUI if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to write your own Red/System routine, a crude solution could be

```
ask-2line: function [quest] [
    collect/into [ 
        keep ask  quest
        keep newline
        keep ask "[  "
    ] clear ""
]

>> ask-2line "what: "
what: 1st line
[  second line
== "1st line^/second line"
```

Of course you have to define how to terminate the input.
e.g

```
ask-nlines: function [quest] [
    collect/into [ 
        while [
            not empty? keep  ask  quest
        ] [
            keep newline
            quest: "{  "
        ]
    ] clear ""
]
```

Comment: a function argument can accept multiple lines, would be great if ask behaved the same.